# Why won't these class attributes multiply?

Tags: python

I have to prompt the user for 2 items. For each Item the program needs to know the name, price, and quantity. Once received it outputs

```
'{Item name} {Item quantity} @ ${Item price} = {Item total}'
```

The item total takes the price and multiplies it by the quantity. However I can't see the total in the output?'

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name = 'none', price = 0, quantity = 0, total = 0):
        self.item_name = name
        self.item_price = price
        self.item_quantity = quantity
        self.total = price * quantity

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.total + other.total

    def print_item_cost(self):
        return print('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total))

#Grab first item
item_1 = Item()
print('Item 1\nEnter the item name:')
item_1.item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_1.item_price = input()
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_1.item_quantity = input()

#Grab second item
item_2 = Item()
print('\nItem 2\nEnter the item name:')
item_2.item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_2.item_price = input()
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_2.item_quantity = input()

#Output cost
print('TOTAL COST\n', item_1.print_item_cost(), item_2.print_item_cost())
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. This will help you understand the differences between what you think your code is doing and what it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating your items using the empty parameter list:

```
item_1 = Item()
```

so that default values are used in `__init__`: `price = 0, quantity = 0`, thus `self.total` is calculated as 0. Later, you change `price` and `quantity` properties of existing object:

```
item_2.item_price = input()
item_2.item_quantity = input()
```

but this does not change `total`.  What you probably should do is:

```
#Grab first item
print('Item 1')
name = input('Enter the item name:')
price = input('Enter the item price:')
quantity = input('Enter the item quanity:')
item_1 = Item(name, price, quantity)
```

(and the same for `item_2`)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the following function is that you are returning a print of the statement. What you need to do is just return the statement and the  print statment from where you made the call will print the returned output. Change from this

```py
def print_item_cost(self):
        return print('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total))
```

To this

```py
def print_item_cost(self):
        return('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total))
```

**Edit:**

Your total value does not change and stays the same once its initialized so add a new calculate total method

```py
def calculate_total(self):
   self.total = self.price * self.quantity
```

And call this method `calculate_total()` for each object to recalculate the total

Comment: You ideally need a method in the class that sets the value of the total after you've taken in all the inputs

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, you are setting the `total` price during initialization, therefore you have to set the `item_price` and `item_quantity` at `__init__`. Another thing when you accept number input from user you have to parse it appropriate data type, because by default it's string.

This would work as you intended it

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name = 'none', price = 0, quantity = 0, total = 0):
        self.item_name = name
        self.item_price = price
        self.item_quantity = quantity
        self.total = price * quantity

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.total + other.total


    def print_item_cost(self):
        return ('{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total))

#Grab first item
print('Item 1\nEnter the item name:')
item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_price = int(input())
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_quantity = int(input())

item_1 = Item(item_name, item_price, item_quantity)


#Grab second item
print('\nItem 2\nEnter the item name:')
item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_price = int(input())
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_quantity = int(input())

item_2 = Item(item_name, item_price, item_quantity)

#Output cost
print('TOTAL COST\n', item_1.print_item_cost(), item_2.print_item_cost())
```

Answer (score 0):

- `total` must be calculated after you provide the actual values
- `input()` returns string in python 3, should be converted to integers (or float)
- changed the name of the `print_item_cost` function and removed `print` from the function; either print or return string but not both

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name = 'none', price = 0, quantity = 0, total = 0):
        self.item_name = name
        self.item_price = price
        self.item_quantity = quantity
#         self.total = price * quantity

    def total(self):
        return self.item_price * self.item_quantity

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.total + other.total


    def item_cost_string(self):
        return '{} {} @ ${} = ${}'.format(self.item_name,
                                              self.item_price,
                                              self.item_quantity,
                                              self.total())

#Grab first item
item_1 = Item()
print('Item 1\nEnter the item name:')
item_1.item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_1.item_price = int(input())
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_1.item_quantity = int(input())


#Grab second item
item_2 = Item()
print('\nItem 2\nEnter the item name:')
item_2.item_name = input()
print('Enter the item price:')
item_2.item_price = int(input())
print('Enter the item quanity:')
item_2.item_quantity = int(input())

#Output cost
print('TOTAL COST\n', item_1.item_cost_string(), '\n', item_2.item_cost_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like

```
self.total = price * quantity
```

It uses the current values of `price` and `quantity` to set the value of `self.total` when this line is executed. This does **not** define a formula that will automatically update `self.total` when the value of `price` or `quantity` changes.